# Job is not triggered with Jenkins Pipeline or Multibranch

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to set up continuous integration with the Jenkins Pipeline plugin and so far it is really disappointing.
I'd really like to put the different build steps in the Jenkinsfile as part of the code.

But the configuration of the Jenkins Pipeline or Multibranch plugin is really poor in my opinion or is just not working.

What I want to achieve is whenever I push something to Github, it triggers a Pipeline job in Jenkins.

I have everything working with a freestyle project but as I said I want to use the Pipeline.

The problems I have with Pipeline:

- It only triggers the job if I push to master when branch to build is */master in the Git plugin configuration.
- If I set the branch to build to empty or **, it does not trigger the job whether I push to develop, master or a feature branch.
- If I add multiple branches to build (*/master, */develop, */feature/*), it does not trigger the job whether I push to develop, master or a feature branch.
- No support for [ci-skip] with additional behaviours "Polling ignores commit with certain messages" though I'm not sure which plugin is responsible for this. (Github, Git, Pipeline or the combination)

The problems I have with the Multibranch:

- After scanning for branches, if I push something new, it does not trigger the build with the changes. I don't want to use polling mechanism. I want webhook mechanism to trigger the jobs.

Does someone have a proper working configuration example not referring to outdated Workflow stuff?

Here is the Jenkinsfile:

```
#!groovy

pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Debug') {
            steps {
                sh 'node --version'
                sh 'npm --version'
            }
        }

        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'npm install'
            }
        }

        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh 'npm test'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you please post your Jenkinsfile so far?

Comment: @arifCee I'm not sure the Jenkinsfile will help but I added it. The different steps work ok when the build is triggered.

Comment: did you read https://thepracticalsysadmin.com/setting-up-a-github-webhook-in-jenkins/ and https://gist.github.com/misterbrownlee/3708738 ?

Comment: I didn't use these articles but I followed similar steps from different articles. I think the problem comes from the interpretation of the "Branches to build" parameter. But the articles you linked don't mention it.